# MediaRecorder on android start failed

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-mediarecorder

I'm trying to make a video recording activity on android using the MediaRecorder within a Cordova plugin and everything loads up fine, but when I click my button Start Recording, I get a message saying "app has stopped working."

Here's the log, I'm not sure what the cause is, as the log does not state. Any help would be appreciated.

```
12-15 01:27:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(776): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-15 01:27:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(776): java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
12-15 01:27:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
12-15 01:27:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at com.ron.camanon.PushCaptureActivity$1.onClick(PushCaptureActivity.java:64)
12-15 01:27:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
12-15 01:27:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:100)
12-15 01:27:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
12-15 01:27:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-15 01:27:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-15 01:27:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-15 01:27:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-15 01:27:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-15 01:27:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-15 01:27:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-15 01:27:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-15 01:27:38.025: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Update: Here's my code on paste bin, and line 64 is mMediaRecorder.start();**

http://pastebin.com/22ZeqS5f

*So my issue now is, I have a black screen for the preview, what am I doing wrong?*

Comment: Logcat on it's own doesn't tell us anything. Post your code and tell us which line is 64 of `PushCaptureActivity`.

Comment: Added code to question via pastebin

Comment: You're setting `mInitSuccesful = true;` on line 125 regardless of whether your try/catch block succeeded or not (in other words, all the `catch` does is call `e.printStackTrace()` and you carry on regardless). Line 64 is `mMediaRecorder.start()` which will almost certainly throw an exception if it isn't in a valid state but you haven't surrounded that line with a try/catch block. Do some better exception handling and you might find the answer.

Comment: Yeah I actually just found this out, so I added exception turns out my preview is invalid, and the preview displays black. Going to debug the preview issue and see where this gets me. Thanks for the help, much needed

Answer (score 0):

> uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO

did you give the app the proper permissions for recorder?

Comment: not sure about cordoba and the permissions, but a normal native app would not work without it

Comment: Yeah I have that, I will post my manifest as well. Patebin here http://pastebin.com/47QabXKr

Comment: RECORD_VIDEO does not exist as a permission.